# JavaScript exercise help setting and getting properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties, undefined-behavior

I'm doing some JavaScript exercises for school and number 8 really has me stumped.

Here is the original complete exercise :

```
/*
 *  @function   {Object} Person
 *  @param      string name
 */
function Person(name) {
    // Todo: Complete the function

}


var Mike = Person('John Doe');
var Bob = Person('John Doe');
var Worker = Person('John Doe');

/*
 * Directions Part 1:
 *  - Update the Person function so the below statements don't generate any errors
 */
Mike.setName('Mike');   // name setter
Mike.getName();         // name getter


/*
 * Directions Part 2:
 *  - Update the Person function so the below statements don't generate any errors
 */
Bob.name('Bob');    // name setter
Bob.name();         // name getter


/*
 * Directions part 3:
 * - Update the Person function so the below statements don't generate any errors
 *
 */
Worker.setName('Kevin');            // name setter
Worker.profession('Programmer');    // profession setter
Worker.profession();                // profession getter

Worker.introduce();                 // Calling this method, the Person will introduce themselves with their name and profession.
```

I think part of my confusion is that I don't quite understand what it's asking of me. The other part is that this style of coding is unfamiliar to me, since I wouldn't usually have floating statements like this.

I suppose the end result should be to give the name and profession, but I can't see a path to get it done the way this is presented.

Comment: `Todo: Complete the function` ... well ... have you? Don't expect us to do your homework for you :p

Comment: No, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823?s=3|0.0000#334823)

Comment: Mike is undefined, if i define it then setName is not a function. I don't understand why it's set up this way?

Comment: @JaromandaX - wonder if that's enough. They aren't creating objects using `new Person()`. It seems like person will need to return something.

Comment: just realised the same think @Mark_M, I guess the idea of this question is to NOT use such objects - i.e. avoid the whole prototypal thing and not use `this` at all - I think Douglas Crawford had a video about that

Comment: What is the idea of it? I've spent about 6 hours looking for anything similar that would give a hint with nothing to show for it.

Comment: *Douglas Crawford javascript without new and this*

Comment: @Jeremy - the way this is setup, `Person()` needs to return an object and that object needs to have properties like `setName` that point to functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's like this:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, I, Person, old = onload; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
Person = function(last, first, middle, job){
  this.first = first; this.middle = middle; this.last = last; this.job = job;
  this.firstName = function(first){
    if(first === undefined){
      return this.first;
    }
    this.first = first;
    return this;
  }
  this.middleName = function(middle){
    if(middle === undefined){
      return this.middle;
    }
    this.middle = middle;
    return this;
  }
  this.lastName = function(last){
    if(last === undefined){
      return this.last;
    }
    this.last = last;
    return this;
  }
  this.profession = function(profession){
    if(profession === undefined){
      return this.job;
    }
    this.job = profession;
    return this;
  }
}
var out = I('out'), newbie = new Person;
newbie.firstName('Bob').lastName('Smith').profession('plummer');
out.innerHTML = newbie.lastName()+', '+newbie.firstName()+'; profession:'+newbie.profession();
/* you wouldn't need to use empty methods, with this design though
out.innerHTML = newbie.last+', '+newbie.first+'; profession:'+newbie.job;
would also work
*/

}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:936px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
#out{
  background:#fff; padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>test</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='out'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```